# How do you Fix the Modulo Function Not Working Correctly for Negative Numbers?

Tags: mathematics

If I make Blender compute a modulo, then it does not work correctly for negative numbers.

In the picture, the part of the rectangular cuboid with a negative abscissa is incorrect.

Here is a render of a rectangular cuboid with a base color of $mod(abscissa,1)$, according to Blender:[image: The modulo function does not work correctly with negative numbers in Blender.]

How you fix that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nowadays, *Wrap* is a simple way to an all-positive modulo:

[image]

Here, on an 8x8 plane. It also allows you to shift 0 without an extra node. There is a vector version, which gives you a sawtooth in any or all dimensions. (A *Wave > Sawtooth* will also do it in one of them, but the scaling is more fiddly.)

Answer (score 3):

The mod returns negative outputs for negative inputs. One way to get positive outputs is

$$((x \operatorname{mod} m) + m) \operatorname{mod} m$$

[image: Nodes for ((x mod 2)+2) mod 2]

[image: Graphs of regular and fixed modulo function]

Comment: Okay, but why does the issue happen?

Comment: It's just a convention. Looks like it ultimately goes through C's `fmodf` function, which has this behavior. See [Modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Comment: It's not "just a convention", at least not as far as the math is concerned..  See my answer for an explanation. but basically it's how Blender clamps negative numbers to 0 when converting to colors.

Comment: @MartyFouts The sign of mod's output is indeed just a convention. For example, GLSL's mod function does what OP expects. See the wiki article for a catalog of the convention in different languages.

Comment: @scurest But that doesn't explain why half of his output is black.  You have to explain why negative numbers come out black.  This is what I was expanding on.

Comment: anyway, your approach generates a lot of overhead and there are far easier fixes.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are seeing is because Blender's gray scale is $[0..1]$ and Blender clamps values < 0  to 0 and values > 1 to 1. So all of your negative values come out as black.  If you had values > 1 they would all come out as white.

While you can use other approaches, an efficient approach to solving this problem is to use the *Map Range* node to map your input values into a positive range:

[image: Module applied to -1 to 1 remapped]

Here I've used a *Texture Coordinate* node to generate the range $[-1..1]$ and a *Map Range* node  to the resulting range $[0..20].  This will give you 10 iterations through the modulo operator set to 2, or 20 set to 1.