# Wrap operator function in Math node?

Tags: node-editor, mathematics

What's the function of the *Wrap* operation under Math node in Blender? It has a value input and a max and min value. Can someone explain its function?

Comment: Hi :). [Blender manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/math.html#properties): "Outputs a value between Min and Max based on the absolute difference between the input value and the nearest integer multiple of Max less than the value."

Comment: See [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/271396/35559). If you copy those 3 or 4 nodes, you'll be able to visualize the function. (It's a positive modulo / sawtooth)